# ZF2 SM, Do I really need to

Tags: zend-framework2

I currently have a ZF2 Module which needs access to three database tables. No other module needs access to these tables.

So my question is (performance in mind too, please) should I really add the factories to the Module.php like I have been doing:

```
/**
 * Service Configuration
 *
 * @return array
 */
public function getServiceConfig()
{
    return array(
        'invokables' => array(
            'Login\Service\Authenticate' => 'Login\Service\Authenticate',
            'Login\Service\Oauth'        => 'Login\Service\Oauth'
        ),
        'factories'  => array(
            'Login\Form\Login'                   => function () {
                $form = new Form\Login();
                $form->setInputFilter(new FormFilter\Login());

                return $form;
            },
            'Login\Model\GaclEmployeePermission' => function ($sm) {
                return new Model\GaclEmployeePermission($sm->get('OTWebsoft\Db\Adapter\Master'), $sm->get('OTWebsoft\Db\Adapter\Slave'));
            },
            'Login\Model\Passport'               => function ($sm) {
                return new Model\Passport($sm->get('OTWebsoft\Db\Adapter\Master'), $sm->get('OTWebsoft\Db\Adapter\Slave'));
            },
            'Login\Model\PassportLog'            => function ($sm) {
                return new Model\PassportLog($sm->get('OTWebsoft\Db\Adapter\Master'), $sm->get('OTWebsoft\Db\Adapter\Slave'));
            }
        )
    );
}
```

Then I have an abstract class which does:

```
/**
 * Table GaclEmployeePermission
 *
 * @return \Login\Model\GaclEmployeePermission
 */
protected function getTableGaclEmployeePermission()
{
    return $this->getServiceManager()->get('Login\Model\GaclEmployeePermission');
}
```

OR should I just remove the configuration from the Module.php and in my abstract class just do this:

```
/**
 * Table GaclEmployeePermission
 *
 * @return \Login\Model\GaclEmployeePermission
 */
protected function getTableGaclEmployeePermission()
{
    return new GaclEmployeePermission($this->getMasterAdapter(), $this->getSlaveAdapter());
}
```

Both seems to work exactly the same. But when it comes to performance, which would you recommend? Keeping in mind, these three tables do not need to be accessed from any other module but this one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main reason to use a service manager or dependency injection container is **not** that other services could access it. The main reason is to apply dependency injection and thereby you apply inversion of control. This ease the usage of your objects, allow you to swap implementations easily, enhance the ability to test the class and to keep the class responsible about the contained logic and not bothering its dependencies.

In both examples, you actually use the service manager but it's still the same pattern: the class (inside `getTableGaclEmployeePermission()`) decides what to get. Either via the service manager or via direct instantiation, that does not actually matter much.

By your module configuration I cannot grasp the layers you have in the application and what they do (esp. what's about that abstract class), but in general, you should inject it's dependencies:

```
abstract class SomeAbstract
{
    protected $permission;

    public function __construct(Permission $permission)
    {
        $this->permission = $permission;
    }
}

class Permission
{
    protected $master;
    protected $slave;

    public function __construct(TableAdapter $master, TableAdapter $slave = null)
    {
        $this->master = $master;

        if (null !== $slave) {
            $this->slave = $slave;
        }
    }
}
```

Then you create the service manager configuration to inject those dependencies for the services you define:

```
'factories' => array(
    'Login\Model\Permission' => function ($sl) {
        $master = $sl->get('My\MasterAdapter');

        $slave  = null;
        if ($some_flag) {
            $slave = $sl->get('My\SlaveAdapter');
        }

        return new Login\Model\Permission($master, $slave);
    },

    'Login\Some\ConcreteImplementation' => function ($sl) {
        $permission = $sl->get('Login\Model\Permission');

        return new Login\Some\ConcreteImplementation($permission);
    }
),
```

Then you request `Login\Some\ConcreteImplementation` and all the injection (`$master`, `$slave` and `$permission`) is done for you, enabling all the benefits described above.

Comment: I go from Module -> Controller -> Service Layer
The Service Layer extends an Abstract Class which implements the SM and other features. I have several Service Layers per Module to split the code up a bit more and to make it easily identifiable (Ie: Add / Edit / Delete). This way each Layer can extend the Abstract Class and not have to Add the features I need to each layer each and every time.

I figured since this particular module is the only one calling those Tables, less configuration in the merged SM would make things a little more lightweight.

Comment: Well, if you have one service per entity, just inject the database adapter in your service class & inject the service in your controller. You only need to do injection once and it keeps the code quite clear.